# Multiple events detected where should only be one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an indicator element that should disappear when I hover it, and replacement should appear on same place.

Now when I leave this replacement, it should now disappear, and old indicator should take it's place again.

Here is a HTML for indicators or triggers:

```
<div class="help-trigger for-desktop">
    <div class="bg">
        <h4>HELP ME<i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i><i class="icon-double-angle-left"></i></h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="help-trigger for-mobile">
    <div class="bg">
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is jQuery code:

```
jQuery('.help-trigger.for-mobile').hover(function(){
    jQuery(this).stop( true, true ).hide();
    jQuery('.help-trigger.for-desktop').stop( true, true).show();
    jQuery('.help-trigger.for-desktop').mouseout(function(){
        jQuery(this).stop( true, true ).hide();
        jQuery('.help-trigger.for-mobile').stop( true, true ).show();
    });
});
```

This in general works, but it sort of flickers and it's unstable. Events get detected more than they should (in lack of better words) so I get too many changes even though I haven't left `.for-desktop` element

Comment: You are binding mouseout event on each `.help-trigger.for-mobile` mouseout/mouseleave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding a `.mouseout()` event handler each time(!) you hover your move over your `.help-trigger.for-mobile` elements. So on each mouseout you call several handlers ... is that your purpose?

EDIT: Additionally, using .hover() with only one callback will add a handler for both mouseenter *and* mouseleave, so you add additional handlers for .mouseout on each mouseenter and mouseleave

Comment: **As a side note:** Not only on hover, but when mouse leaves too because OP is using `hover` method `in/out` handler

Answer (score 0):

Hey i think you trying to achive something like that :

```
$('.help-trigger.for-mobile').hover(function() {
        $(this).hide();     
    }, function() {
        $(this).show();
    });
```

You put a .mouseout inside the mouseover, can't work that way : https://api.jquery.com/hover/